# get ?th element in a string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a string

```
id="123 456 789 321 654 987"
```

I can get the 3rd element from it with:

```
elem=$(echo "${id}" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Here I know I want the 3rd, but what if this "3" is from a variable, say ${num}.
How to get the element which I want.

Yes I can use for loop to iterate ${id} like below:

```
index=1
for i in ${id}; do
  if [ ${index} == ${numchosen} ]
  then
    elem=${i}
  fi  
  index=$((${index}+1))
done
```

But this is stupid. Can I still use the `awk` way, or other simple method. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to use `awk` for a simple task like this, `cut` will work just fine:

```
i=5
id="123 456 789 321 654 987"
elem=$(echo "${id}" | cut -d " " -f ${i})
```

- `-d " "` specified to use the space character as field separator
- `-f N` specified the field you would like to extract.

Answer (score 1):

Say that the variable with the ?th index is `i`:

```bash
i=4
elem=$(echo "${id}" | awk -v N=$i '{print $N}');
```

Should print:

```
321
```

---

From `man awk`:

```
   -v var=val
   --assign var=val
          Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such variable values are available to the BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with bash builtin commands to print element 3:

```
id="123 456 789 321 654 987"
ida=($id)
e=3
echo ${ida[e-1]}
```

Comment: the whole point of the question was to not use a constant to specify the field

Answer (score 0):

Using [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959311/3430492)

```
i=3;cut -d\  -f$i<<<$id
789
```